# Passing BASH arguments

Tags: bash, scripting

[Edit] I've summarized the answer to the following below, the error lies in the line:

[Edit]   **if [$1 ne $value]; then**

---

I'm trying to pass a value to a command:

```
#!/bin/bash
for value in $(mycommand $1)
do
    echo Found $value
    if [$1 ne $value]; then
        echo No match!
    if
done
```

But if I type in the following to execute the script:

```
#./myscript 25
```

I get the error:

```
Found somestuff
./myscript: 25: command not found
```

What I'd like to do is pass in the first argument of the script ("25" in the example above) and send it to the command 'mycommand'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the complete `myscript`? I tried your script as written and got no such error:

```
$ ./myscript.sh 25
Found somestuff
$
```

If I add a `$1` to the end of the script:

```
$ ./myscript.sh 25
Found somestuff
./myscript.sh: line 6: 25: command not found
$
```

Update to your edit: When using the `[` command, you need to add some extra space, and also use `-ne`:

```
if [ $1 -ne $value ]; then
```

The `[` command is often implemented as a soft or hard link to the `test` command, for example:

```
$ ls -l `which [`
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            4 May 16  2006 /usr/bin/[ -> test
```

The manual page for `test` will give more information about the valid expressions.

Comment: Thank for suggesting the "ls -l `which [`" - it pointed to a busybox implmentation.  
Is there another construct I can use for the 'if' statement that I could use as an alternative?

Comment: Using the busybox implementation should be fine. Make sure you put a space after the [, just as you would with any other command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any issue with that script.

```
$ more x
#!/bin/bash
for value in $(echo $1)
do
    echo Found $value
done
$ sh x 28
Found 28
$
```

What is mycommand doing exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Greg pointed me in the right direction, namely:

- add spaces around the [ ] in the if statement, I didn't know they were commands
- the program test doesn't take 'ne' as an argument.

My corrected script is:

```
!/bin/bash
for value in $(mycommand $1)
do
    echo Found $value
    if [ $1 != $value ]; then
        echo No match!
    if
done
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Put a hyphen before the "ne" so you have `-ne`. Also see the Bash `man` page and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 for reasons why `[[` is better than `[` especially concerning the reduced need to quote arguments.